# Porque este templet de twig no me muestra datos en la tabla?

Tags: twig, drupal9

El código que proporcione parece estar destinado a mostrar resoluciones de encargo y resoluciones de nombramiento provisional en una página de Drupal. A simple vista, el código parece estar correcto en términos de estructura Twig.

Sin embargo, hay algunas consideraciones y posibles problemas que debes tener en cuenta:

Comprobar la Existencia de Datos: Asegúrate de que haya datos en node.field_actos_administrativos. Si este campo está vacío o no contiene los tipos de actos administrativos que estás buscando ("resolucion-encargo" y "resolucion-nombramiento"), la tabla no mostrará ningún contenido.

Verifica la Estructura de Datos: Asegúrate de que la estructura de datos en node.field_actos_administrativos coincida con lo que esperas. Debe incluir los campos field_tipo_de_acto, field_descripcion, field_documento, field_fecha, y field_titulo como se utiliza en tu código.

Errores en el Tipo de Acto: Si no se están mostrando datos en las tablas, verifica que los valores en field_tipo_de_acto coincidan exactamente con "resolucion-encargo" y "resolucion-nombramiento". Cualquier discrepancia en los valores podría causar que los actos administrativos no se muestren en las tablas correspondientes.

Verifica la Configuración de Twig: Asegúrate de que la configuración de Twig esté habilitada para la depuración, como lo mencionaste previamente en $settings['twig.config'].

Errores en la Plantilla: Asegúrate de que esta plantilla Twig esté siendo utilizada en el contexto correcto dentro de tu sitio Drupal.

```
<h1>{{ node.title.value }}</h1>

<p>Fecha de Publicación: {{ node.field_fecha_de_publicacion.value|date("d/m/Y") }}</p>

{{ content.field_convocatoria }}

{% set resoluciones_encargo = [] %}
{% for acto in node.field_actos_administrativos if acto.content['#paragraph'].field_tipo_de_acto.value == 'resolucion-encargo' %}
  {% set resolucion_encargo = {
    'descripcion': acto.content['#paragraph'].field_descripcion.value,
    'documento': acto.content['#paragraph'].field_documento.value,
    'fecha': acto.content['#paragraph'].field_fecha|date("d/m/Y"),
    'titulo': acto.content['#paragraph'].field_titulo.value
  } %}
  {% set resoluciones_encargo = resoluciones_encargo|merge([resolucion_encargo]) %}
{% endfor %}

{% set resoluciones_nombramiento = [] %}
{% for acto in node.field_actos_administrativos if acto.content['#paragraph'].field_tipo_de_acto.value == 'resolucion-nombramiento' %}
  {% set resolucion_nombramiento = {
    'descripcion': acto.content['#paragraph'].field_descripcion.value,
    'documento': acto.content['#paragraph'].field_documento.value,
    'fecha': acto.content['#paragraph'].field_fecha|date("d/m/Y"),
    'titulo': acto.content['#paragraph'].field_titulo.value
  } %}
  {% set resoluciones_nombramiento = resoluciones_nombramiento|merge([resolucion_nombramiento]) %}
{% endfor %}

<h2>Resoluciones de Encargo</h2>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Descripción</th>
      <th>Documento</th>
      <th>Fecha</th>
      <th>Título</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for resolucion in resoluciones_encargo %}
      {{ dump(resolucion) }} {# Mostrar información de resolución en la consola #}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ resolucion.descripcion }}</td>
        <td>{{ resolucion.documento }}</td>
        <td>{{ resolucion.fecha }}</td>
        <td>{{ resolucion.titulo }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Resoluciones de Nombramiento Provisional</h2>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Descripción</th>
      <th>Documento</th>
      <th>Fecha</th>
      <th>Título</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for resolucion in resoluciones_nombramiento %}
      {{ dump(resolucion) }} {# Mostrar información de resolución en la consola #}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ resolucion.descripcion }}</td>
        <td>{{ resolucion.documento }}</td>
        <td>{{ resolucion.fecha }}</td>
        <td>{{ resolucion.titulo }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
<div class="actos-admin">
  {{ content.field_descripcion }}
  {{ content.field_documento }}
  {{ content.field_fecha }}
  {{ content.field_titulo }}
</div>
```

el ccodigo tiene como fin mostrar los datos que contiene el paragrahp en forma de tabla , el twig eta en la carpeta templet y cada uno esta en node y el otro en praragrahp